# jQuery working for multiple buttons and divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some trouble on making a button only to show one div, not all of them.

Here's my JS code:

```
$('.show_avatar').click(function(){
$('.avatar').toggle('slow',function() {
    });
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<input class="show_avatar" type="button" value="Show"></input>
     <div class="avatar" style="display:none" class="text-center">
       <%= image_tag d.avatar.url(:medium) %>
     </div>
```

My HTML is in a loop, so it generates multiple buttons with multiple images. When I click in **any** of the buttons (.show_avatar), all the divs appear (.avatar). I know why this happens, but I don't know how to fix it.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8r3to6v8/)**

Without needing any changes to the given HTML, you want to target the element that is the first match of `.avatar` after the button that you click. You can use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

```
$('.show_avatar').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.avatar').toggle('slow',function() {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each in a wrapper

```
<div class="wrap">
    <input class="show_avatar" type="button" value="Show"></input>
    <div class="avatar" style="display:none" class="text-center">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    </div>
</div>
```

and change it to only call it's sibling:

```
$('.show_avatar').click(function(){
$(this).siblings('.avatar').toggle('slow',function() {
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e629orfb/